# Retrieve EKEvent with specific title in EKEventStore

Tags: iphone, ios, ekevent, ekeventstore

Hello i have saved some EKEvent in a specific calendar on iCloud, i want retrieve some of these EKEvent with a specific title, it's possible? i see that there is this method:

```
eventsMatchingPredicate
```

but there is only one predicate:

```
predicateForEventsWithStartDate:endDate:calendars:
```

and i want find EKEvent for title, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you store the ID of the event and then fetch it by using `EKEventStore` method `- (EKEvent *)eventWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`

EDIT: Aha, now I understand your q. Unfortunately the only predicate you can use with EKEventStore is `- (NSPredicate *)predicateForEventsWithStartDate:(NSDate *)startDate endDate:(NSDate *)endDate calendars:(NSArray *)calendars`

So you have to supply a start date and end date to fetch events between those dates. After you have fetched the events you can filter the events by using NSArray `-  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` so there you can give it a predicate with the event's title.

Comment: there are too much, it's simple to me search for the title because have the same title...

Comment: ok thanks, how i can set the title in the predicate? can you give me an example?

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@", titleYourLookingFor]; see more here about predicates https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html

Comment: @Piero Almost 5 years forward and this is still the case. Even `NSCompoundPredicate` with predicate created by `predicateForEventsWithStartDate:endDate:calendars:` and some custom one combined together with `andPredicateWithSubpredicates` causes an error that predicate is invalid.